# Взять индекс из имени файла php

Tags: php

Имеется файл image1.jpg. Как взять цифру из имени файла в php, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: уточните что пробовали и что не получилось.

Comment: непонятен сам алгоритм в php функциях..

Comment: алгоритм php функций описан в исходниках этих функций. зачем вам его понимать ? Замену сделать можно используя regexp например функцией [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) шаблон выглядит так: `/[^\d]/` заменить на `""`

Comment: Спасибо вы ответили на мой вопрос!

Comment: А если имя файлу будет I5mage1.jpg? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не

> А если имя файлу будет I5mage1.jpg? :)

а нужно просто получить цифру то

```
$file = 'image1.jpg';

$index = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $file);

echo $index;
```

Comment: А если имя файлу будет I5mage1.jpg? :)
не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я могу дать тебе идею логики, если тебе нужен индекс, который стоит в конце имени и перед расширением, то можешь просто проанализировать имя файла, найти в нём последнюю "." и от неё в обратном направлении анализировать цифры до тех пор, пока не встретится символ, а потом повернуть символы (если больше 1) по такой же системе.

Comment: сперва я тоже так думал, но позже склонился к preg_replace